# When to use MEM_RESET_UNDO?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to understand why `MEM_RESET_UNDO` exist, and in which situations one should actually use it? quoting [VirtualAllocExNuma](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocexnuma)'s documentation on the flag:

> MEM_RESET_UNDO
> 0x1000000
>
> MEM_RESET_UNDO should only be called on an address range to which MEM_RESET was successfully applied earlier. It indicates that the data in the specified memory range specified by lpAddress and dwSize is of interest to the caller and attempts to reverse the effects of MEM_RESET. If the function succeeds, that means all data in the specified address range is intact. If the function fails, at least some of the data in the address range has been replaced with zeroes.
>
> This value cannot be used with any other value. If MEM_RESET_UNDO is called on an address range which was not MEM_RESET earlier, the behavior is undefined. When you specify MEM_RESET, the VirtualAllocExNuma function ignores the value of flProtect. However, you must still set flProtect to a valid protection value, such as PAGE_NOACCESS.
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista:  The MEM_RESET_UNDO flag is not supported until Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.

Hard to imagine any real-life situation where one would actually want to use it, it sounds like a `oops, I accidentally cleared *important* memory, can I have it back please?` - api

Comment: Maybe a short-lived cache that's only just expired when a request comes in and you want to see if it can be revived?

Comment: I think to understand this we have to consider `MEM_RESET` closely. The use case for which seems to be for discarding some sort of scratch space without giving up the commit. So the OS _must_ keep a page on hand to satisfy that need, just not necessarily that exact page. `MEM_RESET_UNDO` therefore says "I need that back" and if I'm reading it correctly... always succeeds in that specific aspect. The process will have A Page at that address. It just may not be intact however. That's my SWAG.

Answer (score 0):

*MEM_RESET_UNDO should only be called on an address range to which MEM_RESET was successfully applied earlier.* So, the question should be, When to use MEM_RESET?

According to [MEM_RESET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocexnuma), It just make the virtual address return to MEM_COMMIT **initial** state and according to MEM_COMMIT,

> Actual physical pages are not allocated unless/until the virtual
> addresses are actually accessed.

It could mean Actual physical pages are reclaimed but its content is not zeroed, intermediate. If the pages are in [the paging file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/introduction-to-the-page-file),

> The pages should not be read from or written to the paging file.